# Relation doesnt exist Multi-row insert with pg-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm developing a nodejs project with a postgresql-db. 
I've created a table called 'UserAsanas'. It's definitely there, I've checked and re-checked.

But when I try to multi-row insert it keeps telling me the following:

error: relation "UserAsanas" does not exist

```
const cs =  pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['UserID', 'AsanaID', 'RoutineID'], { table: 'UserAsanas' });

const values = [{UserID: 1, AsanaID: 2,RoutineID: 1}, {UserID: 1, AsanaID: 33,RoutineID: 1}];

const multi =  pgp.helpers.insert(values, cs)+ ' RETURNING id';
// INSERT INTO "UserAsanas"("UserID","AsanaID","RoutineID") VALUES(1,2,1),(1,33,1) RETURNING id

db.none(multi).then(data=> {
  res.status(201)
})
.catch( err => {
   return next(err)
})
```

Comment: SQL identifiers (like table and column names) aren't case-sensitive by default -- is it possible that you have a table "userasanas" that you're trying to access as "UserAsanas"? Or vice versa?

Comment: @jmelesky I was going to say the same. It is either that, or he created the table in a non-default schema.

Comment: Thanks, the table is called UserAsanas for sure, and I am able to insert data just by 
`db.one('INSERT INTO UserAsanas (UserID, AsanaID, RoutineID) VALUES (1,2,3) RETURNING ID').then(data=> {
            res.status(201).send(`Asana added to Routine ${routineId} with ID: ${data.id}`)
        })`

Comment: just to add more info, Im using "pg-promise": "^8.6.5" and "bluebird": "^3.5.4"

Answer (score -1):

yep. all small letters and it works like a treat!

```
const single =  pgp.helpers.insert({userid: 1, asanaid: 2,routineid: 1}, null,  'userasanas' );
const multi =  pgp.helpers.insert([{userid: 1, asanaid: 5,routineid: 1}, {userid: 1, asanaid: 4,routineid: 1}], ['userid', 'asanaid', 'routineid'],  'userasanas' );
```

Comment: This means you declared the table incorrectly, using mixed case, but without wrapping it into `""`. Correct your table + columns declaration, using `""`, and that's it. This got nothing to do with `pg-promise`, and this answer is not a good advise.